# Difference between the CLI and the GUI version of Mathematica

Tags: command-line, user-interface, hardware

I have been trying to find out how much faster *Mathematica* is in *CLI* than in *GUI*, and with lack of success in finding any information about it, I decided to crowdsource my quest for this piece of hopefully useful nerdy knowledge.

---

I know that there exist [methods](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/DisplayTheTimingOfAnEvaluationInANotebookWindow.html) for timing the evaluation of the notebook, but here arise my main two problems with timing:

1. I started using *Mathematica* some six months ago, and I realise that I do not yet possess the knowledge and skills to truly test the speed differences in heavier processing. Henceforth, I could only time some relatively lighter processing, which would likely not produce any meaningful difference between the *CLI* and *GUI* (this would reflect my current usage, yes, but I would not learn nothing new for optimising processing for the future).
2. Secondly, I am interested in finding out if the two interfaces use hardware differently, which trial-and-error type timing would not tell me. (E.g. does the *CLI* use the processing computer's processor (and its cores) more efficiently than the *GUI*, or do they use the same interface with comparable results?)

---

While the question admittedly is quite case-specific, I have a few more general questions about the two interfaces' computing speed differences. I know the *CLI* can be commanded to evaluate several notebooks at once, but thinking about **single-notebook** cases:

- Is the *CLI* faster than the *GUI* in *simpler* cases (let's say; evaluation times of <5 seconds), or are the two generally speaking as fast?
- Is the *CLI* faster than the *GUI* in *more complex* cases (let's say; evaluation times of ≥5 seconds), or are the two generally speaking as fast?
- Does the *CLI* use hardware more efficiently than the *GUI*? Are there differences between the two when it comes to utilising multi-core processors?
- Finally: In 2015, is there any and what are the reasons to use the *CLI* over the *GUI* (unless I want to play around with multiple notebooks at once)?

---

While it seems like a simple thing to search for, I could find any general results for the differences between the two, as the choice between using *CLI* or *GUI* seemed to come to people's preferences and the operating system in use.

Comment: There should not be any significant difference except as it concerns display and typesetting. *Mathematica* uses a client/server architecture, and the kernel is a completely separate process to the front end. To the extent that differences exist, it will be due to the terminal application being unable to produce graphical or typeset outputs. Your question is not very well-defined without reference to specific workloads, and your expectations that there could be a difference e.g. in multithreading efficiency do not seem justified by anything in particular.

Comment: As I see it, the principal use case for the terminal application is on compute clusters where you are running batch jobs and do not have (or need) an interactive interface.

Comment: Yeah, the cluster / remote operation of _Mathematica_ naturally begs for the _CLI_, but your mention of _Mathematica's_ client/server architecture makes sense and gives a good idea about if the interfaces true difference.

Comment: @OleksandrR. And it's true the question is not the best-defined question there is, but therein lies the problem; I cannot, with my current _Mathematica_ skills, create "complex" examples of processing a large dataset, for example, so I could not test the difference on my own. Also, any such example would be case-specific, making a general question regrettably specific, which I lament.

Comment: Reasons to use CLI: 1. [run a script](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html) (non-interactive use) 2. run on a remote machine 3. [see messages printed to the terminal](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/displaying-debug-messages-coming-from-librarylink.html) (these might be printed by shared libraries you loaded into Mathematica).  This is only for debugging very special cases.  I almost always use the GUI version.  Oleksandr already said that the kernel process that's being run is the same regardless of whether you run it with or without a front end (GUI).

Comment: To really drive this point home, I wanted to mention that you can even start up a kernel in a terminal, use it for a while, and attach it to a front end (GUI) later!  Finally: certain operations, such as rendering/exporting graphics, require a front end process.  Even if you run Mathematica in a terminal, it will start up a front end process without any visible windows as soon as you try to export or rasterize graphics.

Comment: @Szabolcs Passing the kernel from *CLI* to the front end sounds very compelling; did not know that it would even be possible. And yeah, if both the *CLI* and *GUI* would be reading the same kernel, unless nothing else comes up, I guess the only determining factor in the speed the notebook is evaluated is just the computer's speed of *CLI's* text vs *GUI's* graphical output.

Comment: FWIW the influence of GUI overhead can be observed readily on the RPi version of Mathematica, since the processor is (understandably) under powered for complex math computations and visualizations.